# HTML/CSS - Display the link while hovering over a photo

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, hover

I want to have my link displayed when I hover over the image. The way I wrote the code displays the link only if I hover over the link itself(which is contained in the image div). Any ideas how I should go on?

```css
.image-text-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.image-text-wrapper .xx {
  transition: 1s;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 20px;
}

.image-text-wrapper .xx a {
  color: transparent !important;
}

.image-text-wrapper a:hover {
  color: lightseagreen !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url()">
  <div class="xx">
    <a href="#"> 
            Text 
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So hover on the outside? `.portfolio-img-background:hover {`

Comment: ```.portfolio-img-background:hover a {..... add style here..}``` try this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using just CSS

```css
#image{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:black;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content: center;
}

#link{
  display:none;
}

#image:hover > #link {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
    <div id="image" class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url()">
      <div class="xx" id="link"> 
        <a href="#"> 
          Hi!, im a link
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS class at the bottom of your code can be slightly modified to make this work.

```css
.image-text-wrapper:hover a {
  color: lightseagreen !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```